# Al utilizar "file_put_contents" se genera un archivo "null" al lado del archivo solicitado

Tags: php, archivo, php81

#### Contexto:

Tengo la siguiente situacion; he creado 3 clases:

**- ArgumentLoader:** encargada de recoger cualquier argumento pasado mediante la ejecucion de terminal.
ejemplo: `php index.php -f="output.txt"`

**- BugCatcher:** no es más que una implementacion personalizada para capturar errores en tiempo de ejecucion tanto para entorno web o CLI:

***Ejemplo (capturas):***

- ***Web:***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- ***CLI:***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**- DrawBoxCLI:** En teoria esta es invocada por BugCatcher cuando la instancia de ejecucion es un CLI para mostrar dentro de un layout cuadriculado/marco formateado el error (este es quien arma el ouput de arriba)

Todo lo anteior funciona bien hasta que me percato que no en todas las terminales se podra ver la salida correctamente, algunas terminales como de entornos SSH o Telnet que se conecten de forma remota, no podran renderizar correctanente todos los errores por que tienen limitaciones extrictas del la cantidad de columnas posibles a mostrar.

Entonces se me ocurre la grandiosa idea de implementar que DrawBoxCLI pueda ofrecer la salida mediante un archivo de texto.

#### El problema:

cuando implemento esto:

```
if (file_put_contents($filename, $content) !== false) {/*otro codigo*/}
```

por alguna razon desconocida se me genera un archivo "null"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la clase que hace esto es esta:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Asset\Helper\Error;

class DrawBoxCLI
{
    /**
     * @var DrawBoxCLI|null
     */
    private static ?self $instance = null;

    /**
     * @return self
     */
    public static function getInstance(): self
    {
        if (!self::$instance instanceof self) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

    /**
     * @param array|string $source
     * @param int $nlHeader
     * @param int $nlFooter
     * @param bool $highlight
     * @param int $limitLen
     * @param int $typeOutput
     * @param bool $error
     * @return string
     */
    public function drawBoxes(
        array|string $source,
        int $nlHeader = 0,
        int $nlFooter = 0,
        bool $highlight = false,
        int $limitLen = 0,
        int $typeOutput = 0,
        bool $error = false
    ): string {
        $arguments = ArgumentLoader::getArguments();
        $source = (is_array($source) ? $source : preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', rtrim($source)));
        $isCli = defined('STDIN')
            || php_sapi_name() === "cli"
            || (stristr(PHP_SAPI, 'cgi') && getenv('TERM'))
            || (empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) && !isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && count($_SERVER['argv']) > 0);

        $boxChars = [
            'tl' => '╔',
            'tr' => '╗',
            'bl' => '╚',
            'br' => '╝',
            'v' => '║',
            'h' => '═',
            'hs' => '─',
            'ls' => '╟',
            'rs' => '╢'
        ];

        $colorScheme = ['c' => '', 'r' => ''];

        switch ($typeOutput) {
            case 1: //output message
                $colorScheme['c'] = '[1;42m';
                $colorScheme['r'] = '[0m';
                break;
            case 2: //danger
                $colorScheme['c'] = '[1;41m';
                $colorScheme['r'] = '[0m';
                break;
        }

        $cliColors = [
            'hf' => ($highlight && $isCli && $nlHeader !== 0) ? "\033{$colorScheme['c']}" : '',
            'reset' => ($highlight && $isCli) ? "\033{$colorScheme['r']}" : '',
        ];

        $lenS = max(
            array_map(function ($el) {
                return mb_strlen(preg_replace('/\e[[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]/', '', $el));
            }, $source)
        );

        $termWidth = shell_exec('MODE 2> null') ?? shell_exec('tput cols');
        if (strlen($termWidth) > 5) {
            preg_match('/CON.*:(\n[^|]+?){3}(?<cols>\d+)/', $termWidth, $match);
            $termWidth = $match['cols'] ?? 80;
        }
        $termWidth = (int)$termWidth;

        $longest = ($lenS > $limitLen) ? $lenS : $limitLen;

        if ($limitLen == 0) {
            $longest = $termWidth;
        }

        if ($limitLen == 0 || $this->checkIsFit($longest, $limitLen) || isset($arguments['f'])) {
            $printArea = $longest - 2;
            $result = '';
            $nLines = count($source);
            $i = 0;
            $fTop = $boxChars['tl'] . str_repeat($boxChars['h'], $printArea) . $boxChars['tr'];
            $fBottom = $boxChars['bl'] . str_repeat($boxChars['h'], $printArea) . $boxChars['br'];
            $lineTxt = [];
            $lineTxt[] = $cliColors['hf'] . $fTop . $cliColors['reset'] . PHP_EOL;
            $start = true;
            foreach ($source as $key => $line) {
                $i++;
                if ($nlHeader > 0 && $i <= $nlHeader) {
                    $line = str_pad($line, $printArea, ' ', STR_PAD_BOTH);
                    $lineTxt[] = $cliColors['hf'] . $boxChars['v'] . $line . $boxChars['v'] . $cliColors['reset'] . PHP_EOL;
                    if ($i == $nlHeader) {
                        $lineTxt[] = $cliColors['hf'] . $boxChars['ls'] .
                            str_repeat($boxChars['hs'], $printArea) .
                            $boxChars['rs'] . $cliColors['reset'] . PHP_EOL;
                    }
                } elseif ($nlFooter === 0 || $i <= ($nLines - $nlFooter)) {
                    if ($start) {
                        $lineTxt[] = $cliColors['hf'] . $boxChars['v'] . $cliColors['reset'] .
                            str_pad('', $printArea) .
                            $cliColors['hf'] . $boxChars['v'] . $cliColors['reset'] . PHP_EOL;
                        $start = false;
                    }
                    if ($printArea >= mb_strlen($line)) {
                        $line = ' ' . $line;
                        $line = str_pad($line, $printArea);
                        $lineTxt[] = $cliColors['hf'] . $boxChars['v'] . $cliColors['reset'] . $line .
                            $cliColors['hf'] . $boxChars['v'] . $cliColors['reset'] . PHP_EOL;
                    } else {
                        $chunks = $this->limitLineLength($line, $printArea - 2);
                        foreach ($chunks as $chunkLine) {
                            if ($printArea >= mb_strlen($chunkLine)) {
                                $chunkLine = str_pad($chunkLine, $printArea - 2);
                            }
                            $lineTxt[] = $cliColors['hf'] . $boxChars['v'] . $cliColors['reset'] . ' ' . $chunkLine . ' ' .
                                $cliColors['hf'] . $boxChars['v'] . $cliColors['reset'] . PHP_EOL;
                        }
                    }
                    if ($i === $nLines || ($nlFooter > 0 && $i === $nLines - $nlFooter)) {
                        $lineTxt[] = $cliColors['hf'] . $boxChars['v'] . $cliColors['reset'] .
                            str_pad('', $printArea) .
                            $cliColors['hf'] . $boxChars['v'] . $cliColors['reset'] . PHP_EOL;
                    }
                } elseif ($nlFooter > 0) {
                    $lineTxt[] = $cliColors['hf'] . $boxChars['ls'] .
                        str_repeat($boxChars['hs'], $printArea) .
                        $boxChars['rs'] . $cliColors['reset'] . PHP_EOL;
                    $line = str_pad($line, $printArea, ' ', STR_PAD_BOTH);
                    $lineTxt[] = $cliColors['hf'] . $boxChars['v'] . $line . $boxChars['v'] . $cliColors['reset'] . PHP_EOL;
                }
            }

            if (isset($arguments['f']) && $error === false) {
                $filename = $arguments['f'];
                $lineTxt[] = $cliColors['hf'] . $fBottom . $cliColors['reset'] . PHP_EOL;
                $resultTxt = implode('', $lineTxt);
                $content = $this->RemoveANSSequence($resultTxt);
                $lineTxt[] = $cliColors['hf'] . $boxChars['ls'] .
                    str_repeat($boxChars['hs'], $printArea) .
                    $boxChars['rs'] . $cliColors['reset'] . PHP_EOL;
                if (file_put_contents($filename, $content) !== false) {
                    $line = str_pad("Archivo '$filename' creado exitosamente.", $printArea, ' ', STR_PAD_BOTH);
                } else {
                    $line = str_pad("Error al Crear el Archivo '$filename'!!!", $printArea, ' ', STR_PAD_BOTH);
                }
                $lineTxt[] = $cliColors['hf'] . $boxChars['v'] . $line . $boxChars['v'] . $cliColors['reset'] . PHP_EOL;
            }
            $lineTxt[] = $cliColors['hf'] . $fBottom . $cliColors['reset'] . PHP_EOL;
            $result .= implode('', $lineTxt);
        } else {
            $output = '!!!Your Terminal Windows is too Narrow. Resize It!!!' . PHP_EOL .
                '==> Minimum Expected: ' . $longest . PHP_EOL .
                '==> Given Size:       ' . $limitLen . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL .
                'If you cannot Resize the window;' . PHP_EOL .
                'You can Output the data to a file and avoid this error:' . PHP_EOL .
                'php script.php -f="filename"';
            $result = $this->drawBoxes($output, 1, 1, true, 0, 2, true);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $longest
     * @param int $limitLen
     * @return bool|string
     */
    private function checkIsFit(int $longest, int $limitLen): bool|string
    {
        return ($longest <= $limitLen);
    }

    /**
     * @param $text
     * @param $limit
     * @return array
     */
    private function limitLineLength($text, $limit): array
    {
        $lines = explode("\n", $text);
        $result = [];

        foreach ($lines as $line) {
            $chunks = preg_split('/({[^}]+}|[\/\\\])/', $line, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
            $currentLine = '';

            foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
                if (mb_strlen($currentLine) + mb_strlen($chunk) <= $limit) {
                    $currentLine .= $chunk;
                } else {
                    $result[] = $currentLine;
                    $currentLine = $chunk;
                }
            }

            if (!empty($currentLine)) {
                $result[] = $currentLine;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $resultTxt
     * @return string
     */
    private function RemoveANSSequence(string $resultTxt): string
    {
        $pattern = "/\x1b\[[0-9;]*[A-Za-z]/";
        return preg_replace($pattern, '', $resultTxt);
    }
}
```

#### Update:

El error no esta relacionado a `file_put_contents`, encontre que esta relacionado a los comandos en esta linea:

```
$termWidth = shell_exec('MODE 2> null') ?? shell_exec('tput cols');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, ya esta resuelto, el problema radicaba en todo los lugares en donde se usa:

```
$termWidth = shell_exec('MODE 2> null') ?? shell_exec('tput cols');
```

Fue necesario implementar una metodo nuevo para detectar las columnas disponibles:

```
    /**
     * @return int
     */
    private function detectTermWidth(): int
    {
        $termWidth = null;
        if ($termWidth == null && str_contains(PHP_OS, 'WIN')) {
            $termWidth = shell_exec('mode con');
            preg_match('/CON.*:(\n[^|]+?){3}(?<cols>\d+)/', $termWidth, $match);
            $termWidth = isset($match['cols']) ? (int)$match['cols'] : null;
        } elseif ($termWidth == null && function_exists('shell_exec')) {
            $termResponse = shell_exec('tput cols 2> /dev/tty');
            if ($termResponse !== null) {
                $termWidth = trim($termResponse) ?? null;
                if ($termWidth !== null) {
                    $termWidth = (int)$termWidth;
                }
            }
        }
        if ($termWidth === null) {
            $termWidth = 80;
        }
        return $termWidth;
    }
```

Logre validar la parte de windows; me queda pendiente validar la parte de linux en un futuro, si alguien lo hace antes se les agradece.